# Gulp: Migrating Gulpfile.js from gulp 3 to 4

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

Here i am trying to migrate my existing site which is using gulp 3. Now upgrading gulp from 3 to 4.

Below is Gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
  scsslint = require('gulp-scss-lint'),
  jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
  shell = require('gulp-shell'),
  spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith'),
  browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
  g = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
  reload = browserSync.reload,
  src = {
    scss: '../scss/**/*.scss',
    css: '../css',
    baseCss: '../css/base',
    twigFile: '../pattern-lab/source/_**/**/*.twig',
    jsonFile: '../pattern-lab/source/_**/**/*.json',
    mdFile: '../pattern-lab/source/_**/**/*.md',
    latestChangeFile: '../pattern-lab/public/latest-change.txt',
    javascript: '../js/*.js',
    cssFile: '../css/*.css',
    imageSprite: '../images/sprite/*.png',
  };

// Build pattern-lab
gulp.task('build-pattern-lab', shell.task([
 'cd ../pattern-lab/; M | composer install --no-dev; cd ../.npm/;'
]));

// Task for local, static development.
gulp.task('local-development', gulp.series('sprite', 'style-split', 'pl-generate', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: "../",
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(src.scss, ['style-split']);
  gulp.watch(src.javascript, reload);
  gulp.watch(src.cssFile, reload);
  gulp.watch(src.twigFile, ['pl-generate']);
  gulp.watch(src.jsonFile, ['pl-generate']);
  gulp.watch(src.mdFile, ['pl-generate']);
  gulp.watch(src.imageSprite, ['sprite']);
  gulp.watch(src.latestChangeFile).on('change', reload);
}));

// Sprite.
gulp.task('sprite', function generateSpritesheets() {
  var spriteData = gulp.src('./../images/sprite/*.png')
    .pipe(spritesmith({
      padding: 5,
      imgName: 'sprite.png',
      imgPath: '../images/sprite.png',
      cssName: '_sprite.scss'
    }));

  spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest('./../images/'));
  spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest('./../scss/helpers/'));
  return spriteData;
});

// Sass watch, compile css when sass is changed.
gulp.task('sass-watch', ['style-split'], function () {
  gulp.watch(src.scss, ['style-split']);
});

// SCSS Lint.
gulp.task('scss-lint', function () {
  return gulp.src(src.scss)
    .pipe(
      scsslint({
        'config': 'scss-lint.yml',
      })
    );
});

// Task for compiling sass in development mode with all features enabled.
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  var stream = gulp.src('../scss/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['safari >= 8', 'last 3 versions', '> 2%']}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(src.baseCss));
  return stream;
});

gulp.task('style-split', ['sass'], function() {
  return gulp.src(src.baseCss + "/styles.css")
    .pipe(g.extractMediaQueries())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(src.css));
});

// Generate pattern-lab.
gulp.task('pl-generate', shell.task([
 'php ../pattern-lab/core/console --generate'
]));

// Javascript Lint.
gulp.task('js-lint', function () {
  return gulp.src(src.javascript)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});   
    
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('local-development', function() {
    console.log('Build completed.');
}));
```

When running the default gulp, it's throwing error as, **AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: sprite**

I have used gulp 4 syntax for the task.
Any specific action do i need to perform for migration ? Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining your `"sprite"` task **before** it gets called in the `"local-development"` task (and any others that may fall into the same pattern).

When creating tasks via the `gulp.task(...)` form you do need to have those tasks created (so they can be registered) prior to their being called.  Otherwise you will *forward-referencing* them.

> ##### Forward references
>
> A forward reference is when you compose tasks, using string
> references, that haven't been registered yet. This was a common
> practice in older versions, but this feature was removed to achieve
> faster task runtime and promote the use of named functions.
>
> In newer versions, you'll get an error, with the message "Task never
> defined", if you try to use forward references.

- from [Forward reference documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series/#forward-references)

One advantage of the `function myGulpTask() {...}` form of creating tasks is that do not need to be declared prior to calling them.

Comment: sprite task is defined before calling local development task.

Comment: Your `local-development` task calls the `sprite` task which is defined **after** it and thus registered after it.  Switch the order.  Don't refer to anything that hasn't been defined yet.